# JAVA error finding prime no. between 1 to 20

Tags: java

I'm new and would like to find and correct my errors. I got 2 errors while writing a java program to print prime nos. between 1 to 20.

code:

[image: source code]

error:

[image: Cmd error]

Comment: please include source code in the question (not link!)

Comment: CODE! copy&pastable code! Not image!

Comment: && instead of & should do it.

Comment: Hint: just because 1 is a factor doesn't mean it isn't a prime.

Comment: @Jawad & vs && makes no difference to correctness as none of the conditions has a side effect.

Comment: Its still an error thought.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi why do you think it is an error?

Comment: Misconception I guess!

Answer (score 2):

; instead of ,

```
for (i=1;i<20;i++)
```

Comment: Well, he asked about this error, not to do his homework :)

Comment: i made this program work on my own. I'm glad to see lots of supports here.

Comment: class Prime1to20 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
//initialization
 int i,j,count;
 System.out.print("Prime nos. are: ");
//test no. starts from 20 to 2
 for(i=20;i>1;i--) {
//count is used to count no. of factors for any particular no.  
  count=0;
//inner loop for divisor starting from one less than the no.
  for(j=i-1;j>=1;j--) {
//if no. is factor of the divisor, change divisor and increase the count
   if(i%j==0) count++;
  }
//count which is not changed more than 1( since 1 is a factor of every no.) is prime
  if(count<=1) 
  System.out.print(i+" ");
 }
 
  }
}